# looking for smooth scrolling Slider/carousel without jQuery

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel

I am looking for a pure JS - slider, which allows me to display a carousel, in which all slides are moved smoothly without intermediate stop. The following features would be important:

- autoplay
- supports drag,swipe,responsive
- no dependency on jQuery
- infinite loop
- next / before
- leightweight filesize

I want it feel like a marquee, it should pause on hover, execute the corresponding action directly when clicking forward or back, and continue again after a hover.

Can anyone here recommend me an appropriate slider?

Comment: [https://swiperjs.com/](https://swiperjs.com/) set `freeMode` to `true`. Almost every slider have settings for scroll without snapping

Comment: You can do this with pure CSS... Spend some time on youtube and you will find many examples of pure css only and vanilla JS tutorials on carousels that meet your criteria

Comment: @Greg-- Swiper.js doesnt look bad, but it's really heavy... 136kb, just the js, gzipped. Im looking for a lightweight one.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://swiperjs.com/
it has good documentation and examples and supports frameworks like react.js

Comment: But swiperjs isnt lightweight, its really heavy,sadly